# Wagtail: Can i use the API for fetching read-only drafts of pages for review?

Tags: django, wagtail

The title pretty much sums up the question, the early docs talk about a /revision endpoint but i cannot find if it was ever implemented.

Wagtail have excellent functionality to edit and save the pages, i just need to preview how the draft looks when consumed by my application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API is designed to only serve the live version of pages, to avoid leaking information that isn't intended to be public. However, you can override this behaviour by subclassing `PagesAPIEndpoint` - for example:

```
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import PagesAPIEndpoint


class DraftPagesAPIEndpoint(PagesAPIEndpoint):
    def detail_view(self, request, pk):
        instance = self.get_object()

        if request.GET.get('draft'):
            instance = instance.get_latest_revision_as_page()
        elif not instance.live:
            raise Http404

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then, when registering URL endpoints, use this class in place of `PagesAPIEndpoint`:

```
api_router.register_endpoint('pages', DraftPagesAPIEndpoint)
```

This will give you the ability to pass `?draft=true` in the URL to get back a draft version.

Comment: I added a variant of this solve to my project [wagtail-spa-integration](https://gitlab.com/thelabnyc/wagtail-spa-integration). If anyone is interested in making this better or even upstreaming it, open and issue and let's talk.

Comment: @Bufke I was having a look at your code. I get the most part about computing hash and then providing it to the API to reveal info, however, I did not understand how do you override the URL of the `preview` button to point to the SPA. I also had a look at `_preview_button_on_edit.html` but didn't quite get it. Can you please provide me a pointer here?

Comment: @SanyamKhurana It's overriding [this template](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ee68d2214af95601967ce9cfd1c423bd2606a81e/wagtail/admin/templates/wagtailadmin/pages/_preview_button_on_edit.html) in wagtail. It gets the page url and insert the hash as a query parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *less* hacky approach which doesn't require you to copypaste/rewrite entire internals.

**Note that I use "ViewSet" classes here instead of "Endpoint" as this is the current name of the classes according to the latest versions of Wagtail.**

```py
# This import is just for type annotations; you don't strictly need those.
from django.db.models import QuerySet

from unittest.mock import patch
from wagtail.api.v2.views import PagesAPIViewSet


class DraftPagesAPIViewSet(PagesAPIViewSet):
    def get_base_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        # Replace user_is_staff with whatever you use to check that the request
        #  is authenticated by someone who is allowed to view drafts.
        if user_is_staff(self.request):
            def include_draft_pages(*_args, **_kwargs) -> QuerySet:
                return Page.objects.all()

            with patch("wagtail.query.PageQuerySet.live", new=include_draft_pages):
                queryset: QuerySet = super().get_base_queryset()
        else:
            queryset: QuerySet = super().get_base_queryset()

        return queryset
```

It's still a hack of sorts, but there's really no other way than hacking here.

The reason draft pages are normally not visible through this viewset is that the internal `get_base_queryset` method builds a queryset starting from `Page.objects.all().live()`, which excludes all pages that aren't live (i.e. all drafts.

This solution works by using the standard library's `unittest` module to *temporarily* fake the output of `Page.objects.all().live()` such that it actually just returns ``Page.objects.all()`, effectively including both drafts and non-drafts.   This is done only` if user_is_staff` so that the general public cannot access drafts. If you want you can remove that check, but that means that anyone would be able to see your drafts very easily.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement what [@gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman) stated [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551968/3535547) and also what Bufke mentioned [in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47551049/wagtail-can-i-use-the-api-for-fetching-read-only-drafts-of-pages-for-review#comment102976486_47551968) but I couldn't make it work. I always got Page not found an error when I tried to serialize my instance although the instance was already there.

Further inspection showed that I also needed to override the `get_queryset` method of `PagesAPIEndopint` since it excludes the pages that are not live and thus the serializer throws 404.

So, the final changes would be like this:

```py
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.response import Response
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import PagesAPIEndpoint
from wagtail.api.v2.utils import (
    page_models_from_string,
    BadRequestError,
    filter_page_type,
)


class DraftPagesAPIEndpoint(PagesAPIEndpoint):
    def detail_view(self, request, pk):
        instance = self.get_object()

        if request.GET.get('draft'):
            instance = instance.get_latest_revision_as_page()
        elif not instance.live:
            raise Http404

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request

        # Allow pages to be filtered to a specific type
        try:
            models = page_models_from_string(request.GET.get('type', 'wagtailcore.Page'))
        except (LookupError, ValueError):
            raise BadRequestError("type doesn't exist")

        if not models:
            models = [Page]

        if len(models) == 1:
            queryset = models[0].objects.all()
        else:
            queryset = Page.objects.all()

            # Filter pages by specified models
            queryset = filter_page_type(queryset, models)

        # Filter by site
        if request.site:
            queryset = queryset.descendant_of(request.site.root_page, inclusive=True)
        else:
            # No sites configured
            queryset = queryset.none()

        return queryset
```

and then while registering endpoints use:

```
api_router.register_endpoint('pages', DraftPagesAPIEndpoint)
```

You can use it now with draft query param as `?draft=true` in the endpoint.